# how to get information about currently open project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qt, ide

I'm creating application in C++/Qt and I would like to get some information about currently open project in Eclipse IDE (name, path to the project source, etc.). Is there any existing solution for such need, e.g. some dbus-like interface, or plugin which acts as server (the best would be if that solution worked in the same way on different OSes)? Google didn't help me with this...

Or do i have to write my own plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: maybe there is an API in CDT...

Comment: I need something that does not depend on type of project. My application is in C++/Qt, but i need to get information about any project, it might be java as well as PHP. However i don't need the type, just project name and path to source code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get this information from a separate process. I do not believe there is a ready-made inter-process API for doing this. You will need to write a plugin for Eclipse that will be able to communicate with your C++/Qt app. Inside Eclipse, it is trivial for a plugin to get information about projects, etc.